# How to show data according to some state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react project, on the first row, I have a button that control what button to be shown. Second row is a button to trigger an api call. The response of the api call would be shown on the third line.

However, there is a problem. Let say, I have triggered button A once, and the according data is shown.

Then, I switched from button A to button B, and then I triggered the button B. the according data of B is shown.

However, when I switch back to button A, the data shown on the third row is still about button B.

In fact, even the first time I change the button from A to B, the data showing is from button A, it shouldn't be like that too.

**Q:How could I change the data accordingly?** (say I want the data to be shown is according to that button)

Here is some pictures

[image]

Button have already switch from A to B, but the data is still showing data from A.

[image]

Below is the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export function App(props) {
  const [post, setPost] = useState("");
  const [showAButton, setShowAButton] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(post);
    console.log(showAButton);
  });

  const handleA = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data);
        //set the loading to be false as loading is done
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  };

  const handleB = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2")
      .then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data);
        //set the loading to be false as loading is done
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={(e) => setShowAButton(!showAButton)}>
          Show Load data A button
        </button>
      </div>
      {showAButton ? (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleA}>Load data A</button>
          {post ? <Databoard post={post}></Databoard> : null}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleB}>Load data B</button>
          {post ? <Databoard post={post}></Databoard> : null}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const Databoard = (props) => {
  const { post } = props;
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{post.userId}</li>
      <li>{post.id}</li>
      <li>{post.title}</li>
    </ul>
  );
};
// Log to console
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the loaded data is being held in the state variable, `post` for both A and B. If you want to be able to switch between both bits of data, then you'll need to save both bits of data separately.

First, create `useState` variables to hold both `dataA` and `dataB` separately:

```
  const [dataA, setDataA] = useState("");
  const [dataB, setDataB] = useState("");
```

Then instead of calling `setPost` when you load the data, call the corresponding `setDataA` or `setDataB` for that data:

```
setDataA(response.data);
```

Then update the data display to show the data corresponding to the selected button:

```
      {showAButton ? (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleA}>Load data A</button>
          {dataA ? <Databoard post={dataA}></Databoard> : null}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleB}>Load data B</button>
          {dataB ? <Databoard post={dataB}></Databoard> : null}
        </>
      )}
```

That should do it!

Here's a full working example on CodeSandbox: [image: Edit nifty-neumann-zrznzr]